# Split column values into multiple column values (Generate student attendance report)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to split the data into multiple columns and change column name as well and create percentage based on that split-ed data for student attendance.
Now my table in db is given blow...

```
----------------------------------------------------
StudentID | 11-4-2014 |12-4-2014|13-4-2014|14-4-2014
----------------------------------------------------
1             AA         AP         PP       PA
----------------------------------------------------
2             PP         AA         PP       AP
----------------------------------------------------
```

Here A for Absent, P for present. That AA is for Forenoon Attendance and Afternoon attendance. We need to separate like this..

display attendance based on date and studentid..
here i have used studentid as 1 and 11-4-2014

```
StudentID | Forenoon | Afternoon | Percentage 
---------------------------------------------
1              A          A           0%
--------------------------------------------
2              P          P          100%
-------------------------------------------
```

Its should be based on from... to .. date.
if from date 11.4.2014 to 13.4.2014 then we need to calculate percentage based on dates.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: but the percentage it will show will be for every student one day's attendence only ? am I right ? How will you decide for which date you are splitting data

Comment: what about date in result.. ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete for the expected results. Are you expecting forenoon absent count, forenoon present count and the same for afternoon on an average of all days of the month?

Comment: refer this link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45995/display-monthly-attendance-report-in-mysql

Comment: i want to knw how to split the data by sql query given in that cell....

Comment: Is data will be always two chars?

Comment: S.. ALWAYS 2 CHARS FOR FORENOON AND AFTER NON

Answer (score 0):

to give an answer to your question please refer below

`CREATE TABLE student (studentid INTEGER ,  attendanceDate VARCHAR(20));`

I have created a table and inserted below data in table

```
studentid  attendanceDate
---------  --------------
        1  AA            
        2  AP            
        3  PA            
        4  PP
```

if you will run below query you will get the required output

```
SELECT T.studentid ,T.foreNoon,T.afterNoon, IF(T.forenoon=T.afternoon && T.forenoon ='A', '100%' ,
    IF(T.forenoon=T.afternoon && T.forenoon ='P' , '0%' ,'50%'))     AS percentage
 FROM (
 SELECT studentid, SUBSTRING(attendanceDate,1,1) AS foreNoon,SUBSTRING(attendanceDate,2,1) AS afterNoon  FROM student )T
```

If you run the above query you will get output as given below

```
studentid  foreNoon  afterNoon  percentage
---------  --------  ---------  ----------
    1  A         A          100%      
    2  A         P          50%       
    3  P         A          50%       
    4  P         P          0%
```

Using substring method of MYSQL will solve the problem

Comment: how to assign the date directly..? ur using attendanceDate here..and its not working..

Comment: AttendanceDate is just the columnName where you have attedaneData like AA ,AP you can use your columnName '11-4-2014' in SQL query. What is not working , the example I have written ? or your SQL query ???  Show me create Table script for your **studentattendance** Table

Comment: ya i got the percentge exactly.. but forenoon and after noon column is showing like -,1 in that fields.. here i attached my query which i modified..                                                     "SELECT T.studentid ,T.ForeNoon,T.AfterNoon, IF(T.Forenoon=T.Afternoon && T.Forenoon ='A', '100%' ,
    IF(T.Forenoon=T.Afternoon && T.Forenoon ='P' , '0%' ,'50%')) AS percentage
 FROM (
 SELECT studentid, SUBSTRING($start,1,1) AS ForeNoon,SUBSTRING($start,2,1) AS AfterNoon  FROM session_attdn )T";

Comment: show me create Table script for your **session** and sample data present and pleas paste the output you are getting .

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session_attdn` (
  `StudentID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `29-03-2014` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'WE',
  `30-03-2014` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'WE',
  `31-03-2014` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'WD',
  `01-04-2014` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'WD',
  `02-04-2014` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'WD'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: in percentage column its showing oly 50%.. if i changed the data to 'PP' that time also its showing 50% oly.. and its showing like  13 studentid, forenoon just showing - oly, afternoon 1, in percentage column 50%

Comment: Run the **SELECT studentid, SUBSTRING($START,1,1) AS ForeNoon,SUBSTRING($START,2,1) AS AfterNoon 
  FROM session_attdn**  query only and show me the output . Even if 2-3 rows would be ok for me

Comment: i executed "SELECT studentid, SUBSTRING($start,1,1) AS Forenoon,SUBSTRING($start,2,1) AS Afternoon  FROM session_attdn" now also same 13 in studentid, - in forenoon, 2 in afternoon..

Comment: it means some how the column referred by $start have data '-2' check the data .. thats why I have asked you for sample data present in the table

Comment: sample data: **studentid** | **29-03-2014** | **30-03-2014**  | **01-04-2014** | **02-04-2014** | 13   AP   PP  AA  AP  AA

Comment: if u directly assigned data in substring it will be working perfectly... so nw we need to knw how to assign the data from date field to substring..